# Python - MultiProcessing running only 4 parallel process in 1 CPU core

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, multithreading, multiprocessing

```
N = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
with multiprocessing.Pool(processes = N) as p:
    for result in user_detail:
        arg1 = str(result).replace("[", "\"[")
       arg = arg1.replace("]", "]\"")

        

        #For Linux
        cmd = 'python3 test.py '
        cmd1 = cmd + arg
        
        os.system(cmd + arg + ' &')
```

I have around 10 user details and this for loop will be calling my test.py file parallely. But only 4 parallel jobs are running at a time. How can I make all available 10 users to run parallelly.
In Future user_detail count may increase and I want all to run parallelly..

currently my cpu_count is 1. Testing it with AWS free tier EC2 instance which comes with 1GB RAM.

Someone please help me how to achieve this parallel jobs run using python..
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Don’t know python that much but number of threads that could run at the same time is limited by your machine’s cpu. If you cpu has 8 threads, you cant run more than 8 threads at the same time. If you do, your machine may run 8 of them at the same time as putting the other threads to idle mode. Just keep this in your mind.

Answer (score 0):

You have created a multiprocessing pool, but you have submitted no tasks to it because you have called none of the pool-submitting methods on the pool instance, `p` that you created, such as `map` or `apply_async`.

Because `os.system` creates a process, you should really only need to be using a multithreading pool, which is less expensive to create, and the size of the pool should be the minimum of the number of tasks you will be submitting, i.e. the length of `user_detail`, and the number of CPU cores on the assumption that running the Python interpreter against *test.py* is a fairly CPU-intensive process. If after compiling *test.py* the execution is long-running and involves a lot of network waiting, then the size of the pool should just be the number of tasks you will be submitting.

I have taken the liberty of renaming some variables and simplifying the code for greater clarity:

```py
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
from multiprocessing import cpu_count
import os


def run_cmd(cmd):
    os.system(cmd)

user_detail = [] # ????

N = min(len(user_detail), cpu_count()) # or N = len(user_detail)
# Use multithreading instead of multiprocessing:
with ThreadPool(N) as pool:
    for detail in user_detail:
        arg = str(detail).replace('[', '"[').replace(']', ']"')
        # For Linux:
        cmd = 'python3 test.py ' + arg + ' &'
        pool.apply_async(run_cmd, args=(cmd,))
    # Wait for all tasks to complete:
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. In 1 cpu_count now its running only 3 parallel jobs and I have 5 data in user_details.. Should I go for any session related implementation to run all users at a same time..

Comment: If cpu_count() returns a number 5 or greater then you should be running 5 parallel jobs. But if you only have 3 CPU cores then `N` will be 3. In that case you can use `N = len(user_detail)` and then your pool size will be 5. But, it may not be buy you better performance.

Comment: Is there any other way to achieve it to run around 50 parallel jobs? Creating new session while calling test.py so that it can run parallel for all users.

Comment: I really don't understand your question. What do you mean by "session" and what do you mean by "run parallel for all users." I don't know what you are trying to do. And running  parallel tasks by executing `os.system` to invoke the Python interpreter against a Python file is very inefficient on Linux. You should be importing a function from *test,py*, for example `from test import worker`, and then `pool.apply_async(worker, args=(...))`. What is `test.py` doing? Is it a suitable for multiprocessing? Or would multithreading be better? Or neither?